# Does question about software sell model features and editions belong to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the question about creating/validating selling model of the software. The question could be the following:

> Our company is selling one software in two edition:
>   - cheap one with basic features
>   - expensive one with basic and advance features
>
> According to sells statistic, more than 90% of people are buying the
>   expensive one edition. I would like to know if the sells model is
>   suitable. Isn't the expensive variant too cheap? I know that Microsoft
>   is selling windows or office Home edition and Professional edition,
>   but they don't  sell more than 90% of in Professional edition.
>
> According to the [stackoverflow help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) I can ask question about *a
>   practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development* 
>   but I should ask question about questions about general computing
>   hardware and software.
>
> It seems to me that such product configuration is different in
>   software development,  because production price of creating software
>   copy is same for cheap and expensive edition (which differs for
>   example from automotive where production of luxury car is ore
>   expensive).
>
> Is there some recommended ration in sells for cheap and expensive
>   edition of software to maximize revenue?

I believe that the question is practical and answerable and it is about software development, but I am not sure what exactly means *general computing hardware and software*.

It this question off-topic? If it is, on which Stack Exchange site does it belong?

Answer (score 13):

This is a economics question about selling software.

It's off-topic for SO.
<sup>(And it is probably too broad, elsewhere)</sup>